# Where to provide angular services for storing data

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular2-services, angular-services, ngrx-component-store

I want to use ngrx `component-store`/`service with a subject` in my application, however I am in a situation where I am not sure whats best. I hope you can guide me in the right direction. (The following example is a simplified version of my real scenario).

- I have a `MoviesComponent` with a `MoviesStore`, containing all movies.
- Route `/movies-list` directs to the `MoviesListComponent`. The `MoviesListStore` holds a string which is used for searching in the list
- Route `/movies-detail` directs to `MoviesDetailComponent` and the `MoviesDetailStore` saves the expaned sections in the page.

[image]

This works pretty well.

**BUT**: When I navigate back and forth between `/movies-list` and `/movies-detail` I want that both, `searchFor` and `expandedSections` will preserve its values. With the current architecture the values are discarded since the `MoviesListStore` and `MoviesDetailStore` are destroyed as I navigate between them.

****Approach #1****

I could just move the `MoviesListStore` and `MoviesDetailStore` the the `provider` of `MoviesComponent`.
[image]

- every component still has its own dedicated store
- might be confusing since the store is not provided on the component's level?!

***Approach #2***

I could get rid of the `MoviesListStore` and `MoviesDetailStore` and put the data in into the `MoviesStore` like this
[image]

- The `MoviesStore` now holds every data, no clear separation. The store might become super big.

Comment: Why do you need stores at all? So far I understand `MoviesDetailStore` contains the data of the selected movie that is a result of filtering data from your service by `movieId` parameter. `MovieStore` isn't useful because `MovieComponent` is a shell/container component for list and details. `MoviesListStore` contains the copy of data from the service combined with the current filter state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **Approach #2** is the one you should go with. I agree that when you have a data related only to a specific module or a components subtree there is no need to put it in global store, because of two reasons:

1. It will be available everywhere in your application (using selector)
2. ngrx global store is never destroyed, because it is provided in root. So once you create an instance of it, or you register a [feature](https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/schematics/feature) slice it will always be there, along with the data (you can clear the data manually, but reducer, effects, actions etc. of your feature stays there).

The **Approach #2** is actually called component "branch" state:

> This is the one when you define component store in one node and that state would be used down in the component tree as well

This quote comes from [How to use NgRx ComponentStore? - Alex Okrushko | NG-DE 2022](https://youtu.be/xPmtsD5LRqQ?t=1783). Using this approach, you will have one instance of component store for a specific component subtree. During the navigation between `movies-list` and `movies-detail` components, the data will be preserved, but once the "highest" node is destroyed (in your example its `movies.component`) the component store will also be destroyed along with the stored data. When the instance of `movies.component` is created, an instance of a `movies.store.ts` will be created as well. 
I also recommend checking [component-store vs global store](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/comparison) comparison in official NGRX docs. You might find some answers there as well

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using just a components store in your case is wrong choice because you are limited by a component scope. You kind of realized it because you are here :)

The obvious solution is to introduce a global (i.e., module-level) state to persist the data. Basically, all of your solutions are actually a way of creating this global store.

From your description I can see that you decided not to use NgRX store but to go ahead with an Observable Data Service pattern (that's what you call `service with a subject`). While this is absolutely valid approach, it has its limitations and now you are experiencing one of them.

I don't know why you don't want to use any of the existing global store implementations but I would strongly suggest to take a look on this option as well. It is definitely more complicated but will be more understandable at the end.

"**Approach #1**" is terrible because you separate component store that belong to a particular component and should be visible just from this component from the component itself. I personally wouldn't do it.

"**Approach #2**" is actually a global state :) you just don't call it so. But it has one great disadvantage: data that belongs to `MoviesListComponent` will be stored in `MoviesComponent`.

There are two more ways to solve your problem:

- **Approach #3**: add filters state into page query params during the redirect. The url will look like `http://your.website/movie-details/blahblahblah123?usedFilters=blah`. Redirecting back to movies list will restore the filter state.
- **Approach #4**: involves some UI changes: you can use named router outlets.
  Basically, your URLs will look like `http://your.website/movies-list(sidebar:movie-details/blahblahblah123)?serachFor=blah`. This means that both component instances (`MoviesListComponent` and `MovieDetailsComponent`) are alive simultaneously and `MoviesListComponent` is not destroyed between navigations.

Comment: thx for your answer. However I do NOT want to use a global store here (e.g. ngrx) since I want that all data is cleaned up when I leave the context of `movies.component.ts`

Comment: @matthias interesting. May I ask why? What is your target? BTW, this requirement is also implementable with all the major state management solutions.

Comment: Hi @Volodymyr, #3 and #4 are not applicable to my scenario since the user shall be able to select > 200 elements in the table and I therefore need to reflect 200 UIDs in the url which won't be possible